# Buenas tardes trato de resolver mi problema en mi código pero no me ejecuta

Tags: c#

```
    namespace Impuesto_a_la_renta
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int salario, ingreso, capital, salud, vivienda, alimentacion, educacion, vestimenta,gastosanual;
            double bas,deduccion,Totaldeduccion,total;
            string linea;
            Console.Write(" Ingrese salario laboral:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            salario = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingres sin salario laboral:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            ingreso = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de capital:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            capital = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de salud:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            salud = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de vivienda:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            vivienda = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de alimentacion:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            alimentacion = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de educacion :");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            educacion = int.Parse(linea);
            Console.Write(" Ingresos de vestimenta:");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            vestimenta = int.Parse(linea);
            gastosanual = salud + vivienda + educacion + alimentacion + vestimenta;
            Console.Write(" Gastos personales:" +gastosanual);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            deduccion = total -Convert.ToDouble(total * 1.5);
            Totaldeduccion = gastosanual + deduccion;
            bas = total - deduccion;
            Console.Write("Total de ingreso $", total);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Deducible $", deduccion);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Total deducible $", Totaldeduccion);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Base imponible $", bas);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();

            if (bas <= 11.310)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Impuesto de renta a pagar $0");
            }
            else
                  if (bas == 14.410 & bas < 18.010)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Impuesto de renta a pagar $155");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué momento defines el valor del `total` ?

Comment: En la parte de arriba

Comment: Y cual es el problema, que error te da?

Comment: Una cosa es definir la variable y otra cosa es definir el valor de la misma. En este caso, se considera null, y por lo tanto, las operaciones a realizar te van a dar error.

Comment: @Japv la parte del total

Comment: Pero q error te sale?

Comment: que mensaje de error te da?

Comment: @Japv me salia que tenia que definirla pero ya esta definida le asigne 0 y ejecuto ahora me sale esto

Comment: Ingrese salario laboral:400
 Ingrese sin salario laboral:0
 Ingresos de capital:25
 Ingresos de salud:50
 Ingresos de vivienda:80
 Ingresos de alimentacion:80
 Ingresos de educacion :50
 Ingresos de vestimenta:30
 Gastos personales:290
Total de ingreso $
Deducible $
Total deducible $
Base imponible $
Impuesto de renta a pagar $0

Comment: @Japv  no me da los valores de ingreso ni deducibles ni total deducible

Comment: te falto poner: total = double.Parse(linea);

Comment: @Japv en que donde le asigne el 0 ,le puse y me salio no asigno la variable linea salio como error

Comment: El problema se resuelve así: double bas, deduccion, Totaldeduccion, total = 0;

Comment: @DiegoValladares  mil gracias  ya me ejecuto ,les agradezco mucho

Comment: @Japv gracias te agradezco por tu ayuda me sirvió